# Пропускает выполнение функции printArray

Tags: c++, функции, сортировка

Не могу понять, почему в коде пропускается выполнение функции printArray после ввода значений в массив и после выполнения InsertionSort. Также, после образования кучи (функция heapify) печатает лишнее значение перед массивом. Догадываюсь, что проблема с буфером, но не могу решить. До этого пропускал ввод данных в массив, но удалось поправить.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void InsertionSort (int *tab, int n)
{
    for(int counter=1; counter<n; counter++)
    {
        int temp, iter;
        iter = counter;
        while(iter>0 && tab[iter]<tab[iter-1])
        {
            temp = tab[iter];
            tab[iter] = tab[iter-1];
            tab[iter-1] = temp;
            iter--;
        }
    }
}

void MoveDown (int *tab, int first, int last)
{
      int largest = 2* first +1;
      while (largest <= last) {
        if (largest < last && tab[largest] < tab[largest+1] )
          largest ++ ; /*first ma dwa następniki: lewy w 2*first+1 oraz prawy
                         w 2*first+2, przy czym prawy jest większy od lewego */
        if (tab[first] < tab[largest]) {
        // jeśli trzeba zamień większy następnik z jego poprzednikiem
          swap(tab[first], tab[largest]);
          first=largest;
          largest=2*first+1;
        }
        else largest=last+1; // nastąpi wyjście z pętli; poddrzewo jest kopcem
      }
}

void heapify (int *tab, int n)
{
    for (int i=n/2-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        MoveDown(tab, i, n-1);
    }
}



void printArray (int *tab, int n)
{
    for(int i; i<n; i++)
    cout<<tab[i]<<" ";
}

int main() {

       int ch = 0;
       int size;

       cout<<"Введи размер массива: ";
       cin>>size;
       cout<<endl;
       int tab[size];
       cout<<"Заполняем массив элементами! "<<endl;
       for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
       {
       cout<<"Podaj wartosc elementu "<<i+1<<": ";
       cin>>tab[i];
    }
       printArray(tab, size);
       cout<<endl;

       cout<<"Какой способ сортировки используем: InsertionSort = 1 czy HeapSort = 2 ? : ";
       cin>>ch;
       if(ch == 1)
       {
       InsertionSort(tab, size);
       printArray(tab, size);

       return 0;
    }
       if(ch == 2)
       {
       heapify(tab, size);
       printArray(tab, size);

       return 0;
    }
       cout<<"Неправильный выбор! "<<endl;

       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Приведенный код не компилируется из-за множественных ошибок синтаксиса. Ну и форматирование тоже ужасное.

Comment: Код компилируется, просто я не давал целого кода. Не хватает ещё функций.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как минимум

```
int tab[size-1];
```

маловато для того, чтобы разместить `size` элементов

```
for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    ....
    cin>>tab[i];
}
```

Так что имеем выход за границы массива, и далее — UB — может быть что угодно...

Кстати,

```
int tab[size-1];
```

противоречит стандарту...

Comment: Не знаю, почему меня заклинило на этом. Поправил, но проблема не решилась.

Comment: Надо бы посмотреть коды функций. Вы там в них ничего случайно не читаете из `cin`?

Comment: Добавил весь код. Нет, из `cin` ничего не читаю.

Comment: `void printArray (int *tab, int n)
{
    for(int i; i<n; i++)
        cout<<tab[i]<<" ";
}` — обратите внимание: `i` - неинициализированная переменная... Попробуйте исправить на `int i = 0`, потом будем смотреть дальше :)

Comment: Да, всё дело в этом. Как-то я это пропустил. Спасибо.